# Split the name into Fname, Mname and Lname

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help with this expression

### INPUT

| Fullname |
| --- |
| SZAFLARSKI,ANDRZEJ S |
| SZAFLARSKI,ANDRZEJ Santa |
| SZAFLARSKI rel,ANDRZEJ |

### OUTPUT

| Firstname | Middlename | Lastname |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ANDRZEJ | S | SZAFLARSKI | `This format for length = 1` |
| ANDRZEJ Santa | null | SZAFLARSKI | This `format for length greater than 1` |
| ANDRZEJ | null | SZAFLARSKI rel | `It has to search for firstname after comma(,)` |

If middle name length greater than 1 then firstname is append with middlename and middlename gives null. If middle name length = 1 then split with middle name and First name only up to before space.
The search for Firstname should start from comma(,) and the third scenario should match.

Can anybody help with this with an explanation?

### edit

```sql
select lastN,
       case when length(midN) = 1 then midN end as midN,
       firstN || case when length(midN) > 1 then ' ' || midN end as firstN
  from ( select regexp_substr('BOULAY d,STEPHEN', '([^,]+),', 1, 1, '', 1) as lastN,
                regexp_substr('BOULAY d,STEPHEN', ',([^ ]+)', 1, 1, '', 1) as firstN,
                regexp_substr('BOULAY d,STEPHEN', ' (.+)', 1, 1, '', 1) as midN
           from dual );
```

In this query I have achieved first 2 scenarios but for 3rd it is failing.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? You should at least be able to figure out how to get the last name. Do you know how to find a comma in a string? Do you know how to get a substring of a string? Here is a list of string functions: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Single-Row-Functions.html#GUID-06062705-1EC8-44ED-89B8-0F0573B74EA2. Then, for "if last part is a single character" there is `CASE WHEN` in SQL. Show us what you have and where you got stuck.

Comment: select lastN,
       case when length(midN) = 1
        then midN
       end as midN,
       firstN ||
        case when length(midN) > 1
            then ' ' || midN
        end as firstN
from
(      
    select  regexp_substr('BOULAY d,STEPHEN', '([^,]+),', 1, 1, '', 1) as lastN,
       regexp_substr('BOULAY d,STEPHEN', ',([^ ]+)', 1, 1, '', 1) as firstN,
       regexp_substr('BOULAY d,STEPHEN', ' (.+)', 1, 1, '', 1) as midN
    from dual
);

In this query I have achievedforst 2 scenario but for 3rd its failing

Comment: You can [edit] your question. The SQL in your comment should be in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this :

```
^  -->  Finds regex that must match at the beginning of the line
$  --> Finds regex that must match at the end of the line.
\w --> A word character, short for [a-zA-Z_0-9]
\s --> A whitespace character, short for [ \t\n\x0b\r\f]
```

The function length(regexp_substr(Fullname, ',\w+\s*(\w*)$', 1, 1, '', 1)) returns the length of the Middlename path if exists.

```sql
with your_table (Fullname) as (
select 'SZAFLARSKI,ANDRZEJ S'      from dual union all
select 'SZAFLARSKI,ANDRZEJ Santa'  from dual union all
select 'SZAFLARSKI rel,ANDRZEJ'    from dual
)
select Fullname
, case when length(regexp_substr(Fullname, ',\w+\s*(\w*)$', 1, 1, '', 1)) > 1 
        then regexp_substr(Fullname, ',([^,]+)$', 1, 1, '', 1) 
      else regexp_substr(Fullname, ',(\w+)\s*\w*$', 1, 1, '', 1)
  end FirstName
, case when length(regexp_substr(Fullname, ',\w+\s*(\w*)$', 1, 1, '', 1)) > 1 
        then null
      else regexp_substr(Fullname, ',\w+\s*(\w*)$', 1, 1, '', 1)
    end middleName
, regexp_substr(Fullname, '^[^,]+', 1, 1)Lastname 
from your_table
;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8134c69c3b57d7c6f81a64481eb477ca)

Comment: "You could try this" is not really a good answer. Why *should* they try this? This answer would benefit from an explantion of what the code is doing.

Comment: You are right, I should have put my answer with more explanation. I will do it later, I do not have much time rigth now.

Comment: Now I brought more explanation to my answer. Hope that could help.

Answer (score 0):

With `REGEXP_SUBSTR` you can use `^` for the string's start and `$` for the string's end.

Use `fullname LIKE '% _'` to determine whther there is just one single character after a blank at the end. (You can of course just as well use `REGEXP_LIKE` if you like that better.)

```
select
  case when fullname like '% _'
    then regexp_substr(fullname, '([^,]+) .$', 1, 1, 'i', 1)
    else regexp_substr(fullname, '[^,]+$')
  end as first_name,
  case when fullname like '% _'
    then regexp_substr(fullname, '.$')
    else ''
  end as middle_name,
  regexp_substr(fullname, '^[^,]+') as last_name
from mytable;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c9b94e7ac222ee8c970c111ecd97e269